# Show ad after certain amount of interactions

Tags: ios, xcode6, ads, revmob

I own a simple soundboard app, which basically plays a song when a button is pushed.

I wanted to know, if it was possible to show an ad after a certain amount of user interactions. 
e.g when 20 sounds have been played, a fullscreen ad would pop-up.

I've integrated RevMob in to my app, if that makes any differences :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, with any ad provider (including RevMob), you have pretty decent control on when an ad should appear.

For RevMob, I see you can call "`[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];`" when you want to [show a full screen ad](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#fullscreen) (or `RevMobAds.session().showFullscreen();` if you're using Swift -- you didn't specify).

So just add a counter property in your view controller and increment the number of user interactions you want to keep track of and then show the full screen ad when you're ready.